# InvocationTargetException : On Logout for some Samsung device

Tags: android, reflection

On my logout click,

```
public void logOut(View v){

   LoggedInUser loggedInUser = CommonUtilities.getObjectFromSharedPreferances(this,     Global.LOGGED_IN_HEALOW_USER, LoggedInUser.class);
   CommonUtilities.updateDeviceSessionToServer(this, loggedInUser.getId(), "logout");   

    ----Clearing SharedPreferance-----
}
```

I have a class having some static utilities methods. Using them, I am updating the session to server & clearing shared preferances on logout. The utility method `getObjectFromSharedPreferances` of CommonUtilities is as follow :

```
public static <T> T getObjectFromSharedPreferances(Context context, String key, Class<T> returnType) {
        Object obj = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String jsonStr = settings.getString(key, null);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            obj = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, returnType);
        }
        return returnType.cast(obj);
    }
```

And another Utility method `updateDeviceSessionToServer` just send the session status to server.

But when execution comes on `updateDeviceSessionToServer` method, I am getting exception. Following is the exact line `(Line No 63)` on which exception occurs.

```
CommonUtilities.updateDeviceSessionToServer(this, loggedInUser.getId(), "logout");
```

Also, I am not getting exception for all device. It is happening for some devices, like Galaxy S 2& Galaxy Exhibit.

The full `stackstrace` is as follow :

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2178)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2574)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9238)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2173)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ecw.healow.settings.SettingsMainActivity.logOut(SettingsMainActivity.java:63)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2173)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2574)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9238)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ecw.healow.settings.SettingsMainActivity.logOut(SettingsMainActivity.java:63)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ecw.healow.settings.SettingsMainActivity.logOut(SettingsMainActivity.java:63)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2173)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2574)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9238)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
"
```

I am not getting the clue what is happening there.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by looking at line 63 in `SettingsMainActivity.java` file.  According to the stack trace, you're getting a `NullPointerException` there:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ecw.healow.settings.SettingsMainActivity.logOut(SettingsMainActivity.java:63)
    ...
```

Comment: It is the same line mentioned in question. i.e. `CommonUtilities.updateDeviceSessionToServer(this, loggedInUser.getId(), "logout");`. But I have no clue why this line is throwing `NullPointerException`.

Comment: How about debugging it and stepping through the method?  You can debug on a real phone in a same way as in an emulator.  If you don't have a phone yourself, then separate this call out: check whether `this` is `null` (very unlikely), then check whether `loggedInUser` is `null` (most likely in this case).  Then go from there.

Comment: I have Galaxy Note 2. And in note 2 I never got the exception. I tried with some emulators. But in that also I didn't got exception. My app is there on play store. And for some phones, currently know to me are `Galaxy S 2 & Galaxy Exhibit`, I am getting `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @hemu In this case, as I stated, break the code so that every operation is on a separate line - that way you'll know exactly what causes the exception.  Again, the most likely culprit is `loggedInUser` is `null`.  Try to investigate this.